Hashtags in the activity feed Buddypress
I don’t know where to dig anymore, I’m trying to attach hashtags to the activity feed. I’ve created a separate page and I’m trying to call the entry.php template but it’s not loading properly!
For some reason the styles are not loading correctly. I have attached screenshots.
https://prnt.sc/jEms0Zul8TVY
https://prnt.sc/Roy5fmcWPZCV
And here is the page code itself:
<?php
/*
Template Name: Hashtag Page
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div class="activity" data-bp-single="<?php echo esc_attr( bp_current_action() ); ?>">

    <?php
    if ( isset( $_GET['tag'] ) ) {
        $hashtag = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['tag'] );
        echo '<h1>Hashtag : #' . esc_html( $hashtag ) . '</h1>';

        // Використання BP_Loop для отримання активностей
        if ( bp_has_activities( array( 'search_terms' => '#' . $hashtag ) ) ) : ?>
            <ul id="activity-stream" class="activity-list item-list bp-list" data-bp-list="activity">
                <?php while ( bp_activities() ) : bp_the_activity(); ?>
                    <?php bp_get_template_part( 'activity/entry' ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p>Hashtag.</p>
        <?php endif;
    } else {
        echo '<p>Hashtag.</p>';
    }
    ?>

</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
?>

I will be glad for any suggestion.
